# Any java editor with code completion, that does not require project set up?

Tags: java, ide, editor

I'm looking for a light-weight java editor, as complement to Eclipse, for doing one-off edits of smaller bits of java code, where I don't want to go through the hassle of setting up an eclipse project just to edit a java file in place.

I still want at least code completion, so just picking any text editor isn't an option.

I can live with something more heavy-weight too, just if I can open up the file in place, and edit, without project setup.

(And yes, I run (x)ubuntu)

Comment: How do you imagine code-completion without knowing about every class and interface your application references? Let's say your class uses StringUtils from apache commons library which lies in some weird classpath location loaded by maven. Without setting up the project no editor will know neither about maven, classpath, library or StringUtils. And in case you specify classpath for your projects, it has to be saved somewhere and becomes a full-blown project.

Comment: @Max I'm thinking of something that does a decent job at figuring out some good defaults ... whereafter I can configure it more if I have the time. Would go a long way even if it just covers the standard library.

Comment: I finally resorted to try to set up things correctly in a full-blown IDE. Thing is, it turned out that IntelliJ IDEA made this in a much easier way than Eclipse. In Eclipse, I had to import the file into the workspace, for it to recognize any external libraries I had set up in the project. In IDEA, I could easily just set up a project in place, link my external libraries, and have auto-completion work. A small subtle difference, that makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can add autocomplete feature to any IDE nowadays.

look at [notepad++](http://cybernetnews.com/notepad-50-can-auto-complete-code/)
or [vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C++_code_completion)

I recommend you the use of notepad++ as an extra

Comment: Thanks! I'd much prefer to avoid the hassle of setting up soemthing for vim though (if possible), and notepad++ seems to be only for windows...

Answer (score 1):

For linux: [KATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_%28text_editor%29) and [Sumlime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Comment: Thanks, will have a look!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), also check this [tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcrYo1p0FVw) for further instructions on how to set up JDK.

Answer (score 0):

[SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) is a simple, lightweight, multi-platform editor, based on the same source code editor component than Notepad++.

It allows auto-completion of words existing in the current buffer, and you can add an API file to cover common function calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mave for project management.  Its compatible with most IDEs.

Netbeans has free form project, that could be used.

JEdit is also a good option